# Error inserting time into sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, simpledateformat

I have two strings that I am trying to insert into a table "categories". The strings are "updatedAt" and "createdAt". I have them as strings in the simple date format:

```
SimpleDateFormat mSdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

I am getting an error because the time contains a colon. At least I believe that is what is happening. Here is my insertion code:

```
public void insertCategories(SQLiteDatabase db, int id, String group, String updatedAt, String createdAt){

        String CATEGORY_INSERTION = 
            "insert into " + DATABASE_USERTAG + "(" + KEY_TAGID + ", " + KEY_TAGNAME + ", " + KEY_UPDATED_AT_TAG + ", " + KEY_CREATED_AT_TAG +") " +
            "values(" + id + ", " + group + ", " + updatedAt + ", " + createdAt +");";
        db.execSQL(CATEGORY_INSERTION);
    }
```

Here is the logcat output:

```
    04-20 12:10:38.489: E/Database(629): Failure 1 (near "12": syntax error) on 0x1b8268 when preparing 'insert into UserTag(_id, tagName, udpatedAtTag, createdAtTag) values(1, 'Favorites', 2013-04-20 12:10:38, 2013-04-20 12:10:38);'.
    04-20 12:10:38.519: W/dalvikvm(629): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
    04-20 12:10:38.529: E/AndroidRuntime(629): FATAL EXCEPTION: ModernAsyncTask #1
    04-20 12:10:38.529: E/AndroidRuntime(629): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    04-20 12:10:38.529: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$3.done(ModernAsyncTask.java:137)
    04-20 12:10:38.529: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
    04-20 12:10:38.529: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
    04-20 12:10:38.529: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
    04-20 12:10:38.529: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    04-20 12:10:38.529: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
    04-20 12:10:38.529: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
    04-20 12:10:38.529: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
    04-20 12:10:38.529: E/AndroidRuntime(629): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "12": syntax error: insert into UserTag(_id, tagName, udpatedAtTag, createdAtTag) values(1, 'Favorites', 2013-04-20 12:10:38, 2013-04-20 12:10:38);
    04-20 12:10:38.529: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_execSQL(Native Method)
    04-20 12:10:38.529: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1763)
    04-20 12:10:38.529: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at mcbee.recipeBoXx.honeyComb.RecipeDbAdapterMod$DatabaseHelper.insertCategories(RecipeDbAdapterMod.java:180)
    04-20 12:10:38.529: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at mcbee.recipeBoXx.honeyComb.RecipeDbAdapterMod$DatabaseHelper.onCreate(RecipeDbAdapterMod.java:160)
    04-20 12:10:38.529: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at mcbee.recipeBoXx.honeyComb.RecipeDbAdapterMod$DatabaseHelper.onUpgrade(RecipeDbAdapterMod.java:173)
    04-20 12:10:38.529: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:132)
    04-20 12:10:38.529: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at mcbee.recipeBoXx.honeyComb.CategoryContentProvider.query(CategoryContentProvider.java:88)
    04-20 12:10:38.529: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:187)
    04-20 12:10:38.529: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:262)
    04-20 12:10:38.529: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:49)
    04-20 12:10:38.529: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:35)
    04-20 12:10:38.529: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:240)
    04-20 12:10:38.529: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:51)
    04-20 12:10:38.529: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:40)
    04-20 12:10:38.529: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$2.call(ModernAsyncTask.java:123)
    04-20 12:10:38.529: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
    04-20 12:10:38.529: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  ... 4 more
```

Also if I change simple date format to:

```
SimpleDateFormat mSdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

There are no errors. How do I properly format this string so that it will include the time?

Edit: Figured it out, should have thought of this ... changed the simple date format to this:

```
SimpleDateFormat mSdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH':'mm':'ss");
```

Comment: What is the data type of `udpatedAtTag` andd `createdAt` in your DB Table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the 'quotes' around the strings.

You could use something like this:

```
... ", '" + createdAt + "', '" + ...
```

but it would be much easier to use the [insert](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29) function, which takes care of all that:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put(KEY_TAGID, id);
cv.put(KEY_TAGNAME, group);
cv.put(KEY_UPDATED_AT_TAG, updatedAt);
cv.put(KEY_CREATED_AT_TAG, createdAt);
db.insert(DATABASE_USERTAG, null, cv);
```

Answer (score 0):

store the time as milisoceond. Then to retrieve the data just get the miliseconds time as long value then do some calculation to convert it to formatted time.